# How much should a normal person exercise and what type of exercises he should do to be fit?

Tags: health

Consider a person who don't want to be a bodybuilder/powerlifter/etc and have a daily sitting job , how much and what exercises he should do to maintain his body ?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. You’ve asked two entirely different questions here, and we like to keep posts focused on one question at a time. You’ve already received an answer to the first question in your post, so I’ll go ahead and remove the second question about bodybuilding, which is probably too opinion based for our format anyway.

Comment: A vague question will get vague answers. Maintain your body for...what? Just being healthy? Any sports? Daily living? Age prevention? All similar but there are some differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [World Health Organization's 2020 Adult Physical Activity Guidelines](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/physical-activity) recommend that all adults ages 18-64 years should, at a minimum:

- do at least 150–300 minutes of moderate-intensity aerobic physical activity or at least 75–150 minutes of vigorous-intensity aerobic physical activity; or an equivalent combination of moderate- and vigorous-intensity activity throughout the week
- also do muscle-strengthening activities at moderate or greater intensity that involve all major muscle groups on 2 or more days a week.

Additionally, they advise that people:

- may increase moderate-intensity aerobic physical activity to more than 300 minutes; or do more than 150 minutes of vigorous-intensity aerobic physical activity; or an equivalent combination of moderate- and vigorous-intensity activity throughout the week for additional health benefits.
- should limit the amount of time spent being sedentary. Replacing sedentary time with physical activity of any intensity (including light intensity) provides health benefits, and
- to help reduce the detrimental effects of high levels of sedentary behaviour on health, all adults and older adults should aim to do more than the recommended levels of moderate- to vigorous-intensity physical activity.